# Wildfly 8.2.0 - Module org.hibernate.core:main not found from local module loader

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

When I try to deploy a project, build with gradle, to a wildfly server stated as standalone, the server throws a ModuleNotFoundException exception.

```
2015-01-16 12:03:49,111 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-7) Locally loading module org.hibernate.core:main from local module loader @2471cca7 (finder: local module finder @5fe
5c6f (roots: /home/caco/IdeaProjects/wildfly/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/libexec/modules,/home/caco/IdeaProjects/wildfly/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/libexec/modules/system/layers/base))
2015-01-16 12:03:49,111 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-7) Module org.hibernate.core:main not found from local module loader @2471cca7 (finder: local module finder @5fe5c6f (
roots: /home/caco/IdeaProjects/wildfly/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/libexec/modules,/home/caco/IdeaProjects/wildfly/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/libexec/modules/system/layers/base))

2015-01-16 12:03:49,112 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.logicshop-1.0.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.logicshop-1.0.war".main: JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.logicshop-1.0.war:main
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.hibernate.core:main
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1050) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1406) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1434) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:242) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:70) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 5 more

2015-01-16 12:03:49,151 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "logicshop-1.0.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.logicshop-1.0.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.logicshop-1.0.war\".main: JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.logicshop-1.0.war:main
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.hibernate.core:main"}}
```

The needed `hibernate-core` exists in the filesystem:

```
# cd modules/system/layers/base/org/hibernate/main/
hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar           hibernate-envers-4.3.7.Final.jar         jipijapa-hibernate4-3-1.0.1.Final.jar    
hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar  hibernate-infinispan-4.3.7.Final.jar     module.xml
```

What is the best point to start, searching where the project or the wildfly are mis-configured?

Answer (score 0):

The module present in WildFly is called `org.hibernate`. Your application is trying to import a module `org.hibernate.core`, which does not exist.